# Flickering drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to animate a menu with javascript but I get a weird behavior I don't quite understand. The testing code is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8rpA/1/). If you place your mouse on the Test label the submenu (in navy) should appear. With the mouse in the submenu try to go out of it and then **quickly** get back in. The submenu should flickering forever. I guess the problem lies in the end of the animation not being handled properly but I don't quite understand where I'm wrong.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        Test
        <section class="sub">Test</section>
    </li>
</ul>


.sub {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}

$('#menu li').hover(function() {
    $('#menu .sub').finish();
    $(this).find('.sub').slideDown(400);
},
function() {
    $('#menu .sub').finish();
    $(this).find('.sub').slideUp(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

try this ...

```
$('#menu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".sub").stop();
    $(this).find('.sub').slideDown(400);
},
function() {
    $(this).find(".sub").stop();
    $(this).find('.sub').slideUp(400);
});
```

Comment: doesn't work when you have multiple menu items, the submenu would never slide up completely when you change menu.

Answer (score 0):

`.finish()` method means that if there is animation it have to finish inmediately (and remove queues). `.stop()` method is better for you are looking for.

As point, you can use something like `if( $('.sub', this).is(':animated') ) return;` to prevent new animations while there is still one

edit: [you fiddle modified](http://jsfiddle.net/FNueX/2/)